# Como configurar o PickaDate do Materialize corretamente?

Tags: jquery, materialize

Eu configurei o `pickadate` do [`Materialize`](http://materializecss.com/) numa página só que ele está ficando em inglês e quando eu saio e volto pra aba que tem o `pickadate` ele abre sem eu clicar no campo.

Inseri o `materialize.min.css` no cabeçalho e o `jquery-2.1.1.min.js` e `materialize.min.js` no fim da página.

Còdigo HTML:

```
<div class="input-field col s6">
  <input name="dataIni" type="text" class="dataIniFim">
  <label for="dataIni">Data Inicial</label>
</div>
<div class="input-field col s6">
  <input name="dataFim" type="text" class="dataIniFim">
  <label for="dataFim">Data Final</label>
</div>
```

Depois da importação dos arquivos `javascript no fim da página inseri esse código:

```
$('.dataIniFim').pickadate({
  selectMonths: true, // Creates a dropdown to control month
  selectYears: 15, // Creates a dropdown of 15 years to control year
  dateFormat: 'dd/MM/yy',
});
```

Código para teste: https://jsfiddle.net/Ly52g027/

Comment: Consegues criar um jsFiddle ou montar o código na pergunta que reproduza o problema? Estás a usar algum router?

Comment: Criei o [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ly52g027/).
Quando o foco tá no campo e eu saio e volto ele abre o `pickdate` automaticamente. Está em inglês e ignorando o padrão de formato que informei.

Comment: Percebi que esse comportamento de abrir o datepicker automaticamente ao sair e voltar na aba acontece mesmo no site do materializecss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em relação a idioma do `datepicker`, é somente sobrescrever as definições de inicialização. O fato de abrir automaticamente encontrei uma solução customizando o método `close` tirando o foco do campo:

```js
$('.dataIniFim').pickadate({
  selectMonths: true,
  selectYears: 15,
  // Título dos botões de navegação
  labelMonthNext: 'Próximo Mês',
  labelMonthPrev: 'Mês Anterior',
  // Título dos seletores de mês e ano
  labelMonthSelect: 'Selecione o Mês',
  labelYearSelect: 'Selecione o Ano',
  // Meses e dias da semana
  monthsFull: ['Janeiro', 'Fevereiro', 'Março', 'Abril', 'Maio', 'Junho', 'Julho', 'Agosto', 'Setembro', 'Outubro', 'Novembro', 'Dezembro'],
  monthsShort: ['Jan', 'Fev', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'Mai', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Set', 'Out', 'Nov', 'Dez'],
  weekdaysFull: ['Domingo', 'Segunda', 'Terça', 'Quarta', 'Quinta', 'Sexta', 'Sábado'],
  weekdaysShort: ['Dom', 'Seg', 'Ter', 'Qua', 'Qui', 'Sex', 'Sab'],
  // Letras da semana
  weekdaysLetter: ['D', 'S', 'T', 'Q', 'Q', 'S', 'S'],
  //Botões
  today: 'Hoje',
  clear: 'Limpar',
  close: 'Fechar',
  // Formato da data que aparece no input
  format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
  onClose: function() {
    $(document.activeElement).blur()
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.2/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <form class="col s12">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="input-field col s6">
        <input name="dataIni" type="text" class="dataIniFim">
        <label for="dataIni">Data Inicial</label>
      </div>
      <div class="input-field col s6">
        <input name="dataFim" type="text" class="dataIniFim">
        <label for="dataFim">Data Final</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Caso queira que o `datepicker` feche com apenas 1 clique, pode adicionar também o seguinte trecho:

```
onSet: function( arg ){
    if ( 'select' in arg ){ //prevent closing on selecting month/year
        this.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente. Eu não tinha colocado o `$(document).ready(function() {` talvez seja por isso que não estivesse funcionando a formatação da data.

Comment: @WendelRodrigues, na vdd não, pois o snippet já executa os códigos quando o `DOM` está carregado, eu coloquei por força do hábito mesmo rs

Comment: O problema foram os pontos que apontei na resposta mesmo